# Is there a way to check which domain is accessing my FontAwesome kit?

Tags: font-awesome

Today, out of nowhere, I received an e-mail from FontAwesome warning me that my kit has received over 60% of my allotted 10,000 pageview limit for this month.

Problem is, I don't even know where are these views coming from, and it's from a kit I created over 4 years ago, a time where I worked for a ecommerce development company, so, it can be multiples sites or it can even be only one, but out of hundreds.

I don't have a lot of love for my employer to pay the damn thing, but I'd at least wish to warn they about this upcoming limit and that some icons might be broken.

Is there a way for me to properly check where are the access coming from?

I tried asking for support on FontAwesome site, but support is only given for those who pay for it.